# How do I Lock user in home directory

Tags: java, android, list, directory

I've created a directory at Environment.getExternalStorage() called '/My Webs'. When the app starts it loads the contents of the directory files and sub directories into a list I have a button to go to parent directories, but I don't want the user to go any higher than the root /My Webs directory.

Here is what I've tried:

```
 private void upOneLevel(){
                if(this.currentDirectory.getParent() != null || this.currentDirectory.getParent() != Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "My Webs")
                        this.browseTo(this.currentDirectory.getParentFile());
        }

    private void browseTo(final File aDirectory){
            // On relative we display the full path in the title.
            if(this.displayMode == DISPLAYMODE.RELATIVE)
                    this.setTitle(aDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + " :: " +
                                    getString(R.string.app_name));
            if (aDirectory.isDirectory()){
                    this.currentDirectory = aDirectory;
                    fill(aDirectory.listFiles());
            }else{
                    openFile(aDirectory);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question. If the question is "how do I do this", disable your "button to go to parent directories" when you are at the top of your desired tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
this.currentDirectory.getParent() != Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "My Webs"
```

That is not how you compare strings in Java. Instead, use `equals()` such as:

```
!this.currentDirectory.getParent().equals( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "My Webs" )
```

Comment: I've done that before :) Always forget == is for numerical values only.